# Multiple classes in each element or SASS inheritance/mixins?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I'm planning to refactor the scss code in my React application and I'm trying to understand what is the best practice between these two:

1. Having multiple classes for an element (the main one + the shared classes):

```
 <div class="container-test flex flex-direction-column">Test</div>
```

2. Having only one class (ex. container-test) and using @mixins/@extend inside the scss code:

```
.container-test{
 @include flex.flex;
 @include flex.flex-direction-column;
 ...
}
```

Also I'm trying to consider this point:

- How should I make the shared classes (ex. flex, flex-direction-column) globally available? I  know that the SASS **@import** rule will be deprecated so I'm trying to find a clean way to make shared classes globally available among components without having to import each time the shared scss file in each component (I would use css modules)

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is better.
It uses relatively less keystrokes.

You can use partials to make your SASS organized when using the first approach.

More info: https://youtu.be/9Ld-aOKsEDk

More info: [https://sass-guidelin.es/#:~:text=on%20this%20section.-,The%207%2D1%20Pattern,-Back%20to%20architecture](https://sass-guidelin.es/#:%7E:text=on%20this%20section.-,The%207%2D1%20Pattern,-Back%20to%20architecture)

For the second question, you can create a file named '_index.scss' in your, say abstracts, folder. In that file, forward all your partials. Now you can use that file in your components or main stylesheets and avoid a bunch of extra lines. You can also write a custom namespace name for your abstracts and base and utilities et cetera.

More info: https://youtu.be/CR-a8upNjJ0